# IP restrictions for Power BI Embedded to connect to Mongo database on Mongo Atlas

Tags: powerbi, mongodb-atlas, powerbi-embedded

We have a Mongo database which is hosted on Mongo Atlas. We want to create Power BI reports and have them embedded within our Web Application. All of this is working, however the reports are currently using the data refreshed from Power BI Desktop.

Now we are trying to get the refresh working for the uploaded report in Power BI before we purchase a production node for Power BI Embedded. However, when I try to refresh the data through the Power BI web portal I get the error:

```
Unable to refresh the model (id=4383883) because it references an unsupported data source
```

I suspect this is because we have IP restrictions that limit connections to Mongo Atlas.

Other posts have referred to adding all possible Power BI IP addresses, but that list is huge and changes over time. What other approaches are there? With the reports being used on an Embedded node (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/power-bi-embedded/) does that make things easier?

Comment: At a guess, you need to install a PowerBI gateway on a VM, install the MonogDB ODBC driver on that, and ensure that it refreshes data through that mechanism. AFAIK you must use a gateway because you need to install a special ODBC driver.